# Solution Verification: USA IMO TST 2024 Problem 1

Tags: solution-verification, contest-math

Dear MSE mathematicians,

I had collected this problem from AoPS,though there are many solutions in the thread of this post in AoPS,
I want to verify Mine.Any suggestion for my attempt will be helpful

Thanks

Here is the view of problem and my solution.

USA IMO TST 2024

Find the smallest constant $C > 1$ such that the following statement holds: for every integer $n \geq 2$ and sequence of non-integer positive real numbers $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$ satisfying $$\frac{1}{a_1} + \frac{1}{a_2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{a_n} = 1,$$ it's possible to choose positive integers $b_i$ such that
(i) for each $i = 1, 2, \dots, n$, either $b_i = \lfloor a_i \rfloor$ or  $b_i = \lfloor a_i \rfloor + 1$, and
(ii) we have $$1 < \frac{1}{b_1} + \frac{1}{b_2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{b_n} \leq C.$$
(Here $\lfloor \bullet \rfloor$ denotes the floor function, as usual.)

Can Anyone Verify This Solution Below:(My attempt)

$\textbf{Solution}:$
Let, $C_n>1$ be the smallest positive constant depending on $n$ such that
$$C_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{b_k}>\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n}$$  that satisfy the problem conditions.

As,$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{b_k}>\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n}$$ then aleast one $b_i\geq n-1$. However it is easy to note, if we choose, $$(b_1,b_2,.. ,b_{n-1},b_n)=(n,n,..,n,n-1)$$ we got a possible partition that is greater than $1$ in reciprocal sum of $b_i$,

So, $C_n\leq 1+\frac{1}{n(n-1)}$

$\textbf{Claim}$:There exist a non integer positive real entries $a_i$ such that $b_i=n$ for all $i=1,2,..,n-1$ and $b_n=n-1$, satisfying this problem condition for $a_i$ for all $n\geq 5$

$\textbf{Proof} $: Set, $a_i=\frac{n}{1-\sin^2(u_n)} $ for all $i=1,2,...,n-1$ and $a_n=\frac{n}{1+(n-1)\sin^2(u_n) }$
Let, $a_n=\frac{n}{1+(n-1)\sin^2(u_n)}=n-\frac{3}{2}$
So,we have, $\sin^2
(u_n)=\frac{3}{(2n-3)(n-1)}$

Now,
$$n<\frac{n}{1-\frac{3}{(2n-3)(n-1)}}<n+1$$ for all $n\geq 5$.

So, For all $n>4$
Hence, choose $$b_i=\lfloor a_i \rfloor=n$$ for all $i=1,2,...,n-1$
and choose $$b_n=\lfloor a_n \rfloor+1=n-1$$
$\blacksquare$

Back to the problem,
Set, $C=\max (C_2,C_3,...) $
We can check trial cases, for $n=2,3,4$ which leads to $C\leq\frac{3}{2}$. For $n>4$ we have all $C_n\leq \frac{3}{2}$.  Equality at $C_2=\frac{3}{2}$. Hence we are done.

Comment: Per site rules, for solution verification questions, you need to point out specific parts that you're uncertain about. $\quad$ FWIW I don't think you understand the question. A/ Please define $C_n$ properly. It is $ \neq \sum 1/b_i$.  B/ You've not demonstrated $C_n \leq 1 + 1/n(n-1) $ in the first part of the solution. If anything, it's more that $ C_n \geq 1 + 1/n(n-1)$ (but can we do better on that particular case?). B/ I believe that your claim of $C_2 = 3/2$ is false. Since $ a_1 < 2 < a_2$, by setting $b_1 = 1, b_2 = \lfloor a_i \rfloor + 1 \geq 3$, I get $C_2 = 4/3$.

Comment: Well, Claim is for $n\geq 5$. $C_n$ is the smallest.

Comment: (Last note should be labeled C) I didn't review your claim at all, as it seems to me that you didn't grasp that we can set $b_i$ as we want, IE note C $\quad$  FWIW Introducing $\sin^2 u_n$ is superfluous. You could just say $a_n = n - 3/2,  a_i = (n-1) / (1 - 1/a_n) < (n+1)$.

Comment: Well, Claim is for $n\geq 5$. $C_n$ is the smallest.Also since, $C_n$ is the smallest, it is $\leq$ any partition of reciprocal $b_i$, Also then $C_2\leq 1+\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: $a_i$ is not an integer, but $b_i$ is

Comment: C=(max over All smallest C_n) in my solution

Comment: As I said in the previous comment, I did not review your Claim at all.  $\quad$ As I said in note C above, $C_2 = 4/3$ not $3/2$. If I'm right, then your claim of "Equality at $ C_ 2 = 3/2$" is incorrect.  $\quad$ My main point i that you're not grasping the question, which results in misconceptions and wrong logical arguments. EG Can you write a complete proof for the $n =2$ case?

Comment: (I see you deleted the last comment, so I'm assuming you're starting to grasp at the subtlety of the conditions. I agree that $ C_2 \leq 3/2$, which doesn't invalidate my claim that $C_2 = 4/3$. )

Comment: Okay, Thanks got it.